# How to get values of json arrays in php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, csv

I have a json array within  `{}` braces and which are retrieved from `$response5`.

```
$json ='[
 {
        "Collectioncentre_Name": "Kattupakkam - Collection Centre 001",
        "Session_ID": "20/04/2019/AM/CC001",
        "Date": "2019-04-20T00:00:00",
        "MilkSession": "AM",
        "Farmer_ID": "VASAN/000000037",
        "Row_ID": 332713,
        "Milkman_Code": "310",
        "Farmer_Name": "VASANTHA",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Received_Quantity": 1.3
    },
    {
        "Collectioncentre_Name": "Kattupakkam - Collection Centre 001",
        "Session_ID": "20/04/2019/AM/CC001",
        "Date": "2019-04-20T00:00:00",
        "MilkSession": "AM",
        "Farmer_ID": "CHIND/000000366",
        "Row_ID": 332714,
        "Milkman_Code": "449",
        "Farmer_Name": "CHINDIRA E",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Received_Quantity": 3
    },
    {
        "Collectioncentre_Name": "Kattupakkam - Collection Centre 001",
        "Session_ID": "20/04/2019/AM/CC001",
        "Date": "2019-04-20T00:00:00",
        "MilkSession": "AM",
        "Farmer_ID": "PERUN/000000017",
        "Row_ID": 332715,
        "Milkman_Code": "492",
        "Farmer_Name": "V.Perundevi",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Received_Quantity": 3
    }
]';

 $data=json_decode($json,true);
 $your_string="";

foreach($data as $key=>$v){ 
    $your_string.=$data[$key]['Collectioncentre_Name'].",".$data[$key] 
 ['Session_ID'].",".$data[$key]['Date'].",".$data[$key] 
['MilkSession'].",".$data[$key]['Farmer_ID'].",".$data[$key] 
['Row_ID'].",".$data[$key]['Milkman_Code'].",".$data[$key] 
['Farmer_Name'].",".$data[$key]['Gender'].",".$data[$key] 
['Received_Quantity']."\r\n";
}
$csvdata= trim($your_string, ",");
//$csvdata = $your_string;


echo $csvdata."\r\n";
```

Actually these json arrays are the output from $response5. And if I put the code like `$json ='[$response5;]` instead of adding whole arrays, am not getting the actual result which I got when I added array values. Did I miss anything or did I need to add more code?

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: Instead of $json ='[$response5;] try this way: $json = json_decode($response5, true);

Comment: If you want all of the fields in the loop - you could reduce it to `$your_string.=implode(",",$v).PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Yes, I tried that too `$json = json_decode($response5, true);
echo $json;` but i didnt receive any output.

Comment: `$json ='[$response5;]` is invalid - you should have `$json ="[$response5]";` i.e. double quotes and the `]` inside the `;`.

Comment: Your $json is an array in that code. You can't echo an array

Comment: @NigelRen, Perfect it works....Actually how can I get the headers like "Collectioncentre_Name, Session_ID, Date, MilkSession....." in my downloaded csv file.

Comment: `implode(",",array_keys($data[0]))` should give you the header (I think).

Comment: Yes @NigelRen actually I'm getting only the headers but not the respective values, I need headers and its respective values one by one. Ths is I used `foreach($data as $key=>$v){  $your_string.=implode(",",$v).PHP_EOL;}$csvdata= trim($your_string, ",");echo $csvdata."\r\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the various comments together, when trying to put the whole JSON together from the original data, instead of...

```
$json ='[$response5;]
```

to make it a valid JSON array you need to use...

```
$json ="[$response5]";
```

Then to output each row of data plus headings (using `implode` rather than long winded adding each field together), you can use...

```
$data=json_decode($json,true);
$your_string=implode(",",array_keys($data[0])).PHP_EOL;

foreach($data as $key=>$v){ 
    $your_string.=implode(",",$v).PHP_EOL;
}

echo $your_string."\r\n";
```

Comment: have tried `$json ="[$response5]";$data=json_decode($json,true);$your_string="";foreach($data as $key=>$v){ $your_string.=implode(",",$key).PHP_EOL;$your_string.=implode(",",$v).PHP_EOL;}echo $your_string."\r\n";` but it is not working, anything else need to be add.

Comment: Something more helpful that *it is not working* would help in correcting the problem.

Comment: I used the coding `foreach($data as $key=>$v){$your_string.=implode(",",$v).PHP_EOL;$your_string.=implode(",",$key).PHP_EOL;}$csvdata= trim($your_string, ",");echo $csvdata."\r\n";' but am getting the actual values with one line break and without headers

Comment: Yes I swaped and tried but withouit headers, only values will get displaying and the values displaying like one line gap after another i.e 1st value in row 1 and the next value in row 3...

Comment: Thanks @Nigel Ren, I got the output as much expected, but this time am getting the headers repeats after all the values i.e first headers and it s respective values and next row again headers and its respective values and so on...Is there any way that header will display once in the top .

Comment: Altered code in answer to output only 1 set of headings.

Comment: Great @Nigel Ren, It woks Perfectly....... Thanks again for your valuable time....